# Send email at specific time

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to send email at specific date and time. I cannot set this line:

```
.DeferredDeliveryTime
```

It returns

> Run-time error 440, The object does not support this method.

Cell with date is custom formatted as DD-MMM-YYYY, and
cell with hour is formatted as Time

```vb
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners4_Click()

Dim OutlookApplication As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Ads As String
Dim Subj As String
Dim Body As String
Dim DelDate As Date
Dim DelHour As Integer
Dim DelMin As Integer

    Set OutlookApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApplication.CreateItem(0)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Ads = ws.Cells(4, 2).Value
    Subj = ws.Cells(7, 2).Value
    Body = ws.Cells(4, 9).Value
    DelDate = ws.Cells(10, 6).Value
    DelHour = Hour(ws.Cells(12, 6).Value)
    DelMin = Minute(ws.Cells(12, 6).Value)
   
    With OutlookMail
        .To = Ads
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "REMINDER: " & Subj
        .Body = Body
        .DeferredDeliveryTime = DelDate & DelHour
    End With
   
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApplication = Nothing
       
End Sub
```

[image: This how sheet looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DeferredDeliveryTime` needs a **specific date/time**. Only concatenating the two values **the result will become a string**.

Firstly, declare `Dim DelHour As Date`. It should be something like `02:00:00`. Of course, it may contain minutes, seconds and they should be taken in consideration if needed (`02:20:30`).

Then, try `.DeferredDeliveryTime = CDate(DelDate & " " & DelHour)`

It may work, I think...

Comment: Thank you! Learned something new, it works now!